# Putting RSpec Test Cases in the Right Place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to use RSPec to test my Ruby on Rails 3.2 app.

When I generated the controller, some specs were created for the views and the controller.  I tried adding the following test to the controller spec:

```
it "should have h1 of Home" do
  visit '/home/index'
  page.should have_selector('h1', text: "Home")
end
```

But couldn't get it to pass.

When I ran `rails generate integration_test home` and put the same test in the `homes_spec`, the test works fine.

Why does it matter where the spec goes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to the doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec):

> If you would like to use webrat or capybara with your request specs,
>   all you have to do is include one of them in your Gemfile and RSpec
>   will automatically load them in a request spec.

And request specs live in `integration` and `requests` folders.

Simply.

Comment: So it's a a matter of where capybara is looking?

Comment: yes it is. If you do't have the proper module included, the methods are unknown